# Xamarin forms: App logo in the launching screen of ios app is not center aligned on ipad

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I have used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=y3lspdPxc6o&feature=emb_logo) tutorial video for implementing the splash screen on the ios app. Like the tutorial video, I have added a launch screen file and insert the logo and strip images into it. It is working almost fine on iPhone devices but when it comes to iPad the logo is not in the center.

My design(Have a strip on bottom):

[image]

Current screenshot:

[image]

In iPad, the logo is not on the center and the strip is not on the footer. It behaves like an iPhone size in the IPad device. How can I center the logo and put the strip on the footer for all devices? And what is the best approach for implementing splash in ios?

Comment: "I have added a launch screen file and insert the logo and strip images into it" can you show us the code here?

Comment: @Nikhileshwar there is no code, did you go through the tutorial video. As per the video I have imported the images. Please go through the video, there is no code behind this.

Comment: Have you added all the images into the correct image assets?

Comment: @FreakyAli i am using launchscreen storyboard feature, not assest xcassets feature

Comment: @FreakyAli And my assest xcassets have only appicon option, no launchscreen option. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ltbJ0VvajKLA6QkIrNugVDQE8bzo_Z78

Comment: The constraints that you gave, were they [AutoLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout)?

Comment: @FreakyAli Please have a look at my logo layout window. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H82gauaf1lJunw8EAZ5j18q56BIMOY5E

Comment: @FreakyAli I checked for my another project, it have an additional property Layout and its value Automatic. For this project no such property. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hTL1uetEJimbzkp1tNdipwDMukaWzwch

Comment: When you check that link it will show you how to turn on Auto-sizing also you will have to give the constraints again!

Comment: @FreakyAli I am using Visual studio, in that there is no constraints option.

Comment: You could check the answer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179917/xamarin-forms-app-logo-in-the-launching-screen-of-ios-app-is-not-center-aligned-on-ipad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you had added constraints to your controls. If you consumed **autolayout** to place the controls it will adapter to all size devices including iPads.
Change the mode to constraint mode at the top right side of the designer:

[image]

Use the center point to center a control like:

[image]

Then edit their constants in the property window:

[image]

Click the more button to add leading, bottom, trailing constraints to display a control at the bottom of the view like:

[image]

If it still doesn't work , you could provide a sample and I will check it on my side .

Comment: App logo worked, but the footer strip is not aligned to footer.

Comment: You could share your sample .